# How to parse th:text with whitespace to selectbox in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to use selectbox with this values:

```
  <select th:field="*{branch}" name="branch" class="form-control" id="branch" required autofocus>
      <option th:value="'WEAiI'"th:text="Elektrotechniki Automatyki i Informatyki"></option>          
      <option th:value="'WBiA'"th:text="Budownictwa i Architektury"></option>
  </select>
```

When I call my method I got this exception:

```
 Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could 
 not parse as expression: "Elektrotechniki Automatyki i Informatyki" 
 (template: "auth/register" - line 92, col 52)
```

When I use '_' instead of whitespace all is working correctly.

I tried successless use '&nbsp' like that:

```
 <option th:value="'WBiA'"th:text="Budownictwa&nbsp;i&nbsp;Architektury">
```

Is any way to parse expression with whitespace in select in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround it with quotes, like you are doing for the value:

```
<select th:field="*{branch}" name="branch" class="form-control" id="branch" required autofocus>
    <option th:value="'WEAiI'" th:text="'Elektrotechniki Automatyki i Informatyki'" />
    <option th:value="'WBiA'" th:text="'Budownictwa i Architektury'" />
</select>
```

But you really don't need to use `th:` attributes in this case.  You could do something like this as well.

```
<select th:field="*{branch}" name="branch" class="form-control" id="branch" required autofocus>
    <option value="WEAiI">Elektrotechniki Automatyki i Informatyki</option>          
    <option value="WBiA">Budownictwa i Architektury</option>
</select>
```